# Obviously declared variable is considered undeclared

Tags: c

I have the following code* inside an `if else {}` code block but the GCC compiler throws me this error:

```
hw2b.c: In function `printSymbolK':
hw2b.c:26: parse error before `int'
hw2b.c:27: `w' undeclared (first use in this function)
hw2b.c:27: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
hw2b.c:27: for each function it appears in.)
```

*

```
    int w = 0;
    for(w = 4; w < i; w++) {
      printf(" ");
    }
```

Can someone tell me what i'm missing here? The w variable is declared and initialized inside the if else block but it says it isn't. Any ideas?

EDIT: You were right, i only copied a small piece of my program. Here is the full code:

```
   #include <stdio.h>

/*
* The printSymbolK function accepts a
* natural number (N > 3) and prints the
* symbol K to the console according to certain
* specifications.
*/
void printSymbolK(int N) {
    int i = 0,k=0;
    int katoAkeraioMeros = N/2; // to apotelesma tou pilikou tha strogkilopoihtei pros ta kato dinontas mas to kato akeraio meros tou N/2
    char star = '*';
    for(i = 0;i < N; i++) {
      if( i < katoAkeraioMeros) { // katoAkeraioMeros - i+1 = posa tha einai apo pano
            int res = katoAkeraioMeros - 1; // poses fores tha trexei i epanalipsi
            int l = 0;
            printf("%c",star);
            for(l = i;l < res;l++) {
                printf(" ");
            }
            printf("%c\n",star);
      } else if(i+1 == katoAkeraioMeros) {
        printf("%c%c\n",star,star);
      } else if(i > katoAkeraioMeros) { // auxise to space kata 1 gia kathe i apo edo kai pera
        printf("%c",star);
        int w = 0;
        for(w = 4; w < i; w++) {
          printf(" ");
        }
        printf("%c\n",star);
      } else {
        printf("%c %c\n",star,star);
      }
    }
}

int main() {
  // Stelios Papamichail 4020
  int n = 0;
  do {
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\n\n");
  } while(n <= 3);
  printSymbolK(n);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `parse error before int'`: that's the root cause that confuses the parser. we'd need to see a [mcve] with the error

Comment: You omitted the line that holds the error... don't truncate the code, paste an example we can compiler (with the same compilation error).

Comment: edited, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Your updated code doesn't have the given error.  Did you change something?

Comment: Swap these two lines `printf("%c",star); int w = 0;` and it should compile. If your compiler settings are good, though, it will also tell you something like "'k': local variable is initialized but not referenced".

Comment: @TimRandall that actually worked, thank you! Mind posting it as an answer? Also, why does that throw that error?

Comment: Raster's answer touches on the subject. It's the way C used to work - declare all variables before you can use them. And I can't answer this mysefl because it's "on hold" because a number of people flagged it as problematic - basically because there wasn't enough information. I think perhaps it's okay now, but those people may not return to revise their opinions. The important thing is that you're aware of this issue with your compiler now, so hopefully this won't be a problem any more

Comment: Which version of GCC are you using that it doesn't recognize C99 syntax?  It would have to be very old.

Comment: @TimRandall ok i get it now, thanks a lot

Comment: @JonathanLeffler idk exactly which version but it must be old since its available on your college's pc lab which is kinda old and they dont update stuff

Comment: Run `gcc --version` to find out which version you're using.  Consider adding `-std=c99` or (better `-std=c11` or even `-std=c18`, though if the compiler is old either or both of the 21st century versions may not be supported).

Comment: it says egcs-2.91.57 and i do actually use the std=c99 "command" before running them on the college's pcs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the first error says it all:

```
hw2b.c:26: parse error before `int'
```

So something triggered a syntax error *before* the `int` token.

you shouldn't worry about further errors. at this point the parser is confused and thinks you're using `w` whereas you're trying to declare it (compilers don't stop at the first error so you can fix several errors at once, but sometimes that backfires, and sometimes they stop at some error, and when you fix it, you get *more* errors... compiler does its best with invalid code)

Just fix the *first* error, and retry.

Comment: your code compiles now. maybe you should remove it, as it makes the question look even more bad...

Comment: i am not allowed :(

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the full code, I would guess your using an older C compiler (C89) and you have code that is neither variable definition nor declarations above 'int w = 0;'.